# ResourceUrlEncodingFilter Does Not Version Javascript files

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc

Spring Boot 1.3.3.RELEASE which brings in spring-webmvc 4.2.5.RELEASE does not version Javascript files with the ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.

Project Layout:

[image: Project Layout]

pom.xml:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

WebMvcConfiguration.java:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/**").resourceChain(true)
                .addResolver(new VersionResourceResolver().addContentVersionStrategy("/**"));
    }

    @Bean
    public ResourceUrlEncodingFilter resourceUrlEncodingFilter() {
        return new ResourceUrlEncodingFilter();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work with this configuration.

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
     registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
        .addResourceLocations("/**")
        .resourceChain(true)
        .addResolver(
            new VersionResourceResolver().addContentVersionStrategy("/**"));
}
```

and by turning off Spring Security for javascript files:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {    
    // ...  
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/js/**");
    }
}
```